# Determing which Which georeference system was used on an Ecuadorian Topo Baselayer

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing

I'm creating a map in Western Ecuador, and am attempting to use a military topo baselayer for it.  The map comes with UTM grid lines on it so georeferencing it was easy but I'm unsure of what projection was used for those UTM grid lines on it.  Does anyone know how I could find that out or Where I could find a different topo layer for Ecuador?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be UTM Zone 17 North or South, depending on the latitude. The geographic coordinate reference system (datum) could be one of several based on what's listed in the [EPSG Geodetic Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org):

- PSAD56
- SIRGAS 1995
- WGS 1984

It looks like UTM positions in PSAD56 and either of the other two will differ by a few hundred meters.

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG Geodetic Registry.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time. Turns out it was PSAD56.